# Make RecyclerView + Button scrolling it one piece// Not showing all items with disabling nestedScrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Beneath my RecyclerView is a Button. The RecyclerView´s height is set to `wrap_content`, so when there are a lot of items it takes the full screen and when scrolling to the bottom the Butten is not visible.

I solved this with wrapping these two views inside a ScrollView. This works almost but when scrolling to the button and then up again the RecyclerView start to scroll first while the button is still on the screen. So I needed to disable the scrolling from the RecyclerView itself. I solved this with setting `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`
.

This seems to work but now I have another problem. When having a lot of items the RecyclerView does not show all items only the first few items. This happens with disabling nestedScrolling, when I turn it back on it displays all items again but then I have the previously explained problem.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having the same problem: The solution is to use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView